# Julia - Juno successfully installed but cannot get an output from Juno in Atom (logo of a wheel beside command)

Tags: julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

I'm really sorry, it is probably a very basic question, however i'm stuck

I'm trying to use Juno with Julia on Mac Sierra 10.13.2

I have the followings installed:

Julia 0.6.2
Atom 1.25.0 (and also installed Atom on Julia with `Pkg.add("Atom")`)
in Atom:

uber-juno 0.1.2
julia-client 0.6.10
when trying to run a script, i can't get any output, instead i get a wheel beside the line. I tried to click on it but nothing happens:

[screenshot juno](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcBcl.png)

As an alternative I tried to launch Juno from Julia using using Atom but it unfortunately doesn't work neither

```
julia> using Atom
INFO: Precompiling module Atom.
ERROR: LoadError: HttpParser not properly installed. Please run
Pkg.build("HttpParser")
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./error.jl:30
 [2] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [3] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [4] anonymous at ./<missing>:2
while loading /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/src/HttpParser.jl, in expression starting on line 9
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile HttpParser to /Users/mymac/.julia/lib/v0.6/HttpParser.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] compilecache(::String) at ./loading.jl:710
 [2] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:463
 [3] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:405
 [4] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [5] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [6] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [7] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [8] anonymous at ./<missing>:2
while loading /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpServer/src/RequestParser.jl, in expression starting on line 16
while loading /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpServer/src/HttpServer.jl, in expression starting on line 12
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile HttpServer to /Users/mymac/.julia/lib/v0.6/HttpServer.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] compilecache(::String) at ./loading.jl:710
 [2] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:463
 [3] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:405
 [4] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [5] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [6] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [7] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [8] anonymous at ./<missing>:2
while loading /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/Mux/src/server.jl, in expression starting on line 1
while loading /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/Mux/src/Mux.jl, in expression starting on line 24
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile Mux to /Users/mymac/.julia/lib/v0.6/Mux.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] compilecache(::String) at ./loading.jl:710
 [2] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:463
 [3] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:405
 [4] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [5] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [6] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [7] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [8] anonymous at ./<missing>:2
while loading /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/Blink/src/content/content.jl, in expression starting on line 1
while loading /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/Blink/src/Blink.jl, in expression starting on line 9
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Blink to /Users/mymac/.julia/lib/v0.6/Blink.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] compilecache(::String) at ./loading.jl:710
 [2] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:463
 [3] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:405
 [4] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 [5] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [6] anonymous at ./<missing>:2
while loading /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/Atom/src/Atom.jl, in expression starting on line 5
ERROR: Failed to precompile Atom to /Users/mymac/.julia/lib/v0.6/Atom.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] compilecache(::String) at ./loading.jl:710
 [2] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:497
 [3] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:405
```

I then tried the command `Pkg.build("HttpParser")` without success

```
julia> Pkg.build("HttpParser")
INFO: Building HttpParser
INFO: Attempting to create directory /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/downloads
INFO: Directory /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/downloads already exists
INFO: Attempting to create directory /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/downloads
INFO: Directory /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/downloads already exists
INFO: Downloading file https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser/archive/v2.7.1.zip
INFO: Done downloading file https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser/archive/v2.7.1.zip
INFO: Attempting to create directory /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps
INFO: Directory /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps already exists
INFO: Path /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/src/http-parser-2.7.1 already exists
INFO: Attempting to create directory /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/usr/lib
INFO: Directory /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/usr/lib already exists
INFO: Changing directory to /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/src/http-parser-2.7.1
INFO: Changing directory to /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/src/http-parser-2.7.1
INFO: Changing directory to /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/src
INFO: Attempting to create directory /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/usr/lib
INFO: Directory /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/usr/lib already exists
INFO: Changing directory to /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/src
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
============================================[ ERROR: HttpParser ]============================================

LoadError: failed process: Process(setenv(`make -j8 -C http-parser-2.7.1 library`,String["XPC_FLAGS=0x0", "PATH=/Applications/Julia-0.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin:/Applications/Julia-0.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin:/Users/mymac/anaconda3/bin:/Users/mymac/anaconda/bin:/Applications/Python/anaconda/bin:/Applications/Python/anaconda/bin:/Users/mymac/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin", "PWD=/Users/mymac", "DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.z6Xf4yXyzt/org.macosforge.xquartz:0", "XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0", "TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal", "SHELL=/bin/bash", "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0", "LC_CTYPE=UTF-8", "SONAME=libhttp_parser.dylib", "TMPDIR=/var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/", "TK_LIBRARY=/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts", "FONTCONFIG_PATH=/Applications/Julia-0.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/etc/fonts", "SHLVL=0", "LOGNAME=mymac", "TERM_SESSION_ID=EEE9213F-9771-4947-8280-FAAAA95EBD7D", "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.P76OjxwzrV/Listeners", "Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ps9thmS8pf/Render", "USER=mymac", "TERM=xterm-256color", "HOME=/Users/mymac", "TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=400", "OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE=1"]), ProcessExited(1)) [1]
while loading /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6/HttpParser/deps/build.jl, in expression starting on line 71

=============================================================================================================

==============================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]===============================================

WARNING: HttpParser had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in /Users/mymac/.julia/v0.6
 - build the package(s) and all dependencies with `Pkg.build("HttpParser")`
 - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

=============================================================================================================
```

Many thanks in advance for your feedbacks

Comment: `uber-juno` should normally install required packages for Julia in the first run. Can you remove the packages you installed and try again?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Hckr. I uninstall and re-installed the following packages on Atom: uber-juno, Hydrogen, julia-client, language-julia. In Julia itself i did the following: `Pkg.rm("Atom")` and then `Pkg.add("Atom")` but it still doesn't work. Is it because i cannot see the console in Atom? Maybe it's because of that. How can i display it? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What I suggested was to remove the package `Atom` from Julia. Then run Atom application and try to run a julia code. It should normally install the necessary packages in Atom. If it does not, go to the preferences of `uber-juno` remove the tick from `Disable` option and restart Atom. To open a console, you can search Console in commands (`Ctrl+Shift+P`) or directly use the shortcut `Ctrl+J Ctrl + O`. Do not install `Atom` package in Julia yourself. https://github.com/JunoLab/uber-juno/blob/master/setup.md

Comment: Followed your information but didn't work: I removed Atom from Julia with command `Pkg.rm("Atom")`, then I disabled `uber-juno` from Atom, restarted Atom, but still did't work. In the meantime I found how to open the console by going to Packages > Julia > Open Console. I then could see the error message ` HttpParser not properly installed. Please run
Pkg.build("HttpParser")`. I ran `Pkg.build("HttpParser")`in Julia but got error message `HttpParser had build errors`. I think there are other issues regarding this specific problem. If you have any ideas. Otherwise many thanks @Hckr

Comment: Sorry I see the problem now. Have you installed xcode command line tools? You need it to build HttpParser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
crun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

This line indicates that you probably have not installed xcode command line tools, or you have a path problem. So the builder cannot find the necessarry commands to build `HttpParser`

If you have not installed xcode command line tools, you can do so by running the following command in your OS terminal.

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

and then click install.

https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HttpParser.jl/issues/52

http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html

After installing the tools, you should be able to build `HttpParser` by running `Pkg.build("HttpParser")` on Julia.

Comment: I have a similar problem on Windows 10 (Julia - Juno successfully installed but cannot get an output from Juno in Atom (logo of a wheel beside command)). How can that be solved?

Comment: @Gakuo What error do you get after issuing `using Atom` on the julia REPL? Is it the same error?